# str_ireplace() with keeping of case

Tags: php, match, case-insensitive, replace

How can I use str_ireplace (or something similar) to replace some text for formatting and then return it with the same caps?

Example:

```
$original="The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.";
$find="thE";

print str_ireplace($find,'<b>'.$find.'</b>',$original);
```

That will output:
**thE** quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.

I want it to keep the original case and only apply the formatting, in this example, bold text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
$original = "The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.";
$new = preg_replace("/the/i", "<b>\$0</b>", $original);
```

gives "**The** quick red fox jumps over **the** lazy brown dog." If you want to match specific words, you can add word boundaries: `preg_replace('/\bthe\b/i', ...`.

If you want to parameterize the replacement, you can use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote):

```
 preg_replace('/\b' . preg_quote($word, "/") . '\b/i', "<b>\$0</b>", $original);
```

Comment: *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Comment: Add `u` modifier for UTF-8 support

Answer (score 4):

Either replace with the exact word, or use preg_replace:

```
preg_replace('/(The)/i', "<strong>$1</strong>", $original);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written an alternative solution (a function which uses pure string replacement) to do the job, which allows you to easily set the prefix and suffix (for highlighting):

```
function replace_keep_case($st1, $find1) {

/// set prefix and suffix here
$prefix="<span style='color:red;'><b>";
$suffix="</b></span>";

$index=0;
$resultstring="";
   while ($index < strlen($st1)) {
      if (strtoupper(substr($st1, $index, strlen($find1)))==strtoupper($find1)) {
        $resultstring.=$prefix.substr($st1, $index, strlen($find1)). $suffix;
        $index=$index+strlen($find1); 
      } else {
        $resultstring.=substr($st1, $index, 1);
        $index++;
      }
    }
   return $resultstring; 
}
```

For example:

```
$text="CHICHiOn Ichiro's Malt & Grain (Limited Edition) 700ml 48% CONDITION";

$findstring="ion";

echo replace_keep_case($text, $findstring);
```

Comment: Will it work with spaces and Danish characters.